# How do I setTimeout a large amount of times? Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I am trying to setTimeout a amount of times. I mean i could simply do it like this but I feel like there is a way better way to the same thing. Using a for-loop doesn't feel efficent at all (though I'm a newbie and have no idea).

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000, i++;){
    setTimeout(myFunction, 5);
}
function myFunction(){
    //Do something cool
}
```

Thanks and please don't use any JQuery

Comment: `setTimeout(myFunction, 5*i);` ?

Comment: How about using `setInterval()` instead?

Comment: Neither of the above are particularly useful - the `5 * i` still creates 1000 concurrent timers, and `setInterval` is generally best avoided because it has poor timing guarantees.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I have a feeling your code doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: @Alnitak, What do you suggest then ? I guess `1000` timers are fine if they are serving the purpose..I assume this is a sample code!

Comment: It would be more usual to use a pseudo-recursive loop and just have one pending timer at any one time

Comment: Put the setTimeout call inside myFunction. You just need to make sure you have an escape clause to stop the calls when you are done.

Comment: Do you really want `myFunction` to be called 1000 times 5 milliseconds from now, or do you want `myFunction` to be called 1000 times every 5 milliseconds?

Comment: @markbernard putting the timeout inside `myFunction` would IMHO be wrong - if that function can be called standalone then it shouldn't have repetition logic built into it

Comment: Focusing on the problem alone; it seems you just want to control the timing of a timeout. The loop is a solution rather than the problem itself. If this is true, why not just do this:  
setTimeout(myFunction, (5*duration) ); where duration is a variable that controls the timing of the timeout. It gives you the same time as the loop, less the "does not feel right"

Comment: @Alnitak If you have a function that you want to call often, say to update your interface based on a web service call then you will lock your display in that function by looping all the time. If when I enter a page and call my refresh function once I can have a setTimeout inside the refresh function to continually call itself without disrupting the page rendering.

Comment: @markbernard IMHO the management of the repetition and the function being repeated should be decoupled - that's good software design practise.

Comment: @Alnitak point me to an example that does it without locking the display and I will concede the point.

Comment: @markbernard not sure what you're getting at - I'm not talking about just having a recursive loop, I'm just saying that the function that does that refresh should _only_ do that, precisely once, and that a separate function should take care of calling the refresh function as required.  (kind of how I've done in my answer below).   You might for example want to do a one-off refresh _without_ starting a new timer loop.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a useful pattern for pseudo-recursively calling a function `f`, `n` times, with a delay in between:

```
function setTimeoutRepeat(f, delay, n) {
    (function loop() {
        if (n-- > 0) {
            f();
            setTimeout(loop, delay);
        }
    })();
}

setIntervalRepeat(myFunction, 5, 1000);
```

Comment: If regular periods are important and the work is somewhat time-consuming, setInterval could be a better fit. tail-called setTimeout can spread out over time, so that it could take more than 5000ms to complete, whereas an interval should be done in 5000ms. vauge needs on OP's part though...

Comment: @dandavis I've alluded to it in the comments above, but the problem with `setInterval` is the converse - if timer events get missed (perhaps because the tab is in the background, or because the function takes too long) then `setInterval` events can stack and then they all get triggered immediately without waiting the specified delay between each iteration.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I don't know why you don't like for() loop, maybe you like recursion more:

```
function myFunction(){
    //Do something cool
    console.log('Cool!\n');
} 

(function re(i) {  
    if (i>0) {
        setTimeout(myFunction, 5);
        re(i-1);
    } 
}) (1000);
```

Note, that this solution is less effective as it inherently uses stack (or whatever substitutes it in JS) for recursive calls.

You could also think about using map() function, but again, you'll have to store an array somewhere. Good old for() loop would be your best shot in this case.

Comment: but there's no timers in this ?

Comment: Thanks Alnitak, I've missed to wrap myFunction() with setTimeout().
Edited the answer.

Comment: This will not work. the function re will be called a thousand times before myFunction is called once. Since Javascript is single threaded the timeout calls will pile up until the current thread exits. Add a console message to the re function and it can see it in action. That is why the timeout has to be called inside the myFunction.

Comment: markbernard, thank you, and you are right. I tried it before sending my answer. and it works exactly as you describe. 

But, I think, my solution just corresponds to the question - "to setTimeout a amount of times". Emil (the question's author) exactly wrote  "setTimeout(myFunction, 5)". Maybe the intentions behind the question were different, but I'm trying to answer the question as it is put here.